# Weakly positive form that is not positive

Tags: differential-forms, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold of (complex)dimension $k$ and $\alpha$ be a smooth $(p,p)$ form on $X$. Then $\alpha$ is said to be positive if for each point, there exists an open set where $\alpha$ can be written as finite sum of forms $(i\beta_{1}\wedge\bar{\beta_{1}})\wedge\ldots(i\beta_{p}\wedge\bar{\beta_{p}})$, where $\beta_{i}$ are smooth $(1,0)$ forms on that set.
On the other hand, $\alpha$ is weakly positive if $\alpha\wedge\beta$ is a positive $(k,k)$ form for any positive $(k-p,k-p)$ form $\beta$ on $X$. Now, from the definition of a positive form, it is clear that any positive form is weakly positive. But I can't think of any weakly positive form which is not positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like $i(dz_1\wedge d\bar z_2 + dz_1\wedge d\bar z_1)$ in $\Bbb C^2$ (or $i(dz_1\wedge d\bar z_2 + dz_3\wedge d\bar z_3)$ in $\Bbb C^3$)?

Comment: Yes. Both will work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The two notions coincide for $(1,1)$-forms, by diagonalizing the associated Hermitian form. See Prop. 2.15 in *Degenerate Complex Monge-Ampère Equations* by V. Guedj and A. Zeriahi.